# Drawing shadow around NSImageView

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, nsimageview

I'm trying to draw shadow under an `NSImageView`. I'm accessing the `CALayer` of the view and setting its shadow properties there:

```
[self.originalImageView setWantsLayer:YES];
CALayer *imageLayer = self.originalImageView.layer;
[imageLayer setShadowRadius:5.f];
[imageLayer setShadowOffset:CGSizeZero];
[imageLayer setShadowOpacity:0.5f];
[imageLayer setShadowColor:CGColorCreateGenericGray(0, 1)];
imageLayer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

But even though I have set masks to bounds as NO, I'm getting this:

[image]

Look carefully at the shadow. It is displayed perfectly horizontally, but vertically, it's clipped. The image is aspect-fitted, and both the image and the image view can be arbitrary size. If I try it with `NSShadow` instead of layer's shadow, I'm getting exactly the same results. I could use `myView.clipsToBounds = NO` in iOS and it used to solve this problem, however I can't find that property on Mac.

How can I draw shadow under arbitrary-sized `NSImageView` without clipping?

Comment: I don't have an answer either. Only thing I can tell you is that the shadow seems to be clipped to the view (yours is obviously wider than the image, but same height). Sadly, masksToBounds = NO doesn't help here.

Comment: with the latest xcode, i've discovered that I can apply CI filters to views (I don't know if that feature was also available before or not.) and I went and applied a shadow on my image view *on the container view's layer*. it works perfectly. bottomline: if I apply the filter on image view's own layer, the same thing happens, but if I apply it on the container view's layer, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest Xcode, I've discovered that I can apply CI filters to views (I don't know if that feature was also available before or not.) and I went and applied a shadow on my image view on the container view's layer. It works perfectly. Bottomline: If I apply the filter on image view's own layer, the same thing happens, but if I apply it on the container view's layer, it works!